# Can't understand AND operator in a line of code in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following function which basically asks user to enter the choice for "X" or "O". I used the while loop to keep asking user until I get the answer that's either "X" or "O".

```
def player_input():

    choice = ''

    while choice != "X" and choice != "O":
        choice = input("Player 1, choose X or O: ")

    pl1 = choice

    if pl1 == "X":
        pl2 = "O"
    else:
        pl2 = "X"

return (pl1, pl2)
```

The above code works fine but I quite don't understand how that 'and' works in this particular scenario. If I understand it right, 'and' means both conditions have to be true. However, choice can only be either "X" or "O" at any given time.

Please help me understand this. Apologies in advance if you think this is a dumb question. I am new to python and programming in general.

Thank you!

Comment: It reprompts the user until they provide either X or O.

Comment: You may be thinking of `choice == "X" and choice == "O"`, which would never be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the choice starts off as blank before entering the while loop. During the while loop, the player is asked to choose X or O. The condition enforces the user to input either X or O. If the user types Z, then the condition is true and repeats the loop asking for another input. If the user types X or O, the condition now returns false and the while loop is exited.

Answer (score 0):

In English the condition says "your choice is not X and your choice is not O", in other words "your choice is neither X nor O". It's part of a while, so basically it's saying it will loop until you *don't* give it something that's neither X nor O. In other words it will only stop looping when you give it an X or an O.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, it works, but is also difficult to understand. Others have already explained how it works, but I'd like to propose another version of the function which does the same thing but is shorter and more easily understandable:

```
def player_input():
    choice = ''
    while choice not in ["X" ,"O"]:
        choice = input("Player 1, choose X or O: ")             
    return choice

choice = player_input()
```

Answer (score 0):

The 'and' connects the two checks on the variable 'choice'. If both are true, it will repeat, if one is false, it will drop out of the 'while'. If you put brackets around it maybe it's a bit more clear.

while (choice is not 'X') and (choice is not 'O'):

First you check if choice is not 'X', if that is true, check if choice is not 'O', if that is also true, you have 'true' and 'true', which is 'true'.
If choice is either 'X' or 'O' you get either 'false' and 'true' or 'true' and 'false', which is 'false'.

In general, for any 'and' to be true, both sides of the 'and' have to be true.
For 'or' only one of the sides has to be 'true' to evaluate to 'true'.

Answer (score 0):

I think what's really confusing you is that you don't believe

- `not x and not b == not (x or b)`
- `not x or not b == not (x and b)`

however I can assure you this is the case. In fact, here's a whole wikipedia page on [demorgans theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws) (which states the above) proving that is is.